# Rails console history command (via pry) -- can it be grepped or tailed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, history, irb, pry

In Rails 4 `rails console` I can type `history` and it will behave just like the `history` command from the bash shell.  E.g.:

```
[25] my_rails_project »  history
  1: Nomination
  2: {:ad => "asdfsdasadf"}
  3: Nomination.count
  4: Nomination.count.to_sql
  5: Nomination.all.class
  6: Nomination.all.to_sql
  ...
```

Is there a way to search that history, e.g. `history | grep Nomination`?  How about tail?

Note:  When I initially wrote this question I thought the `history` command came from Rails itself, but it comes from the `pry` gem which I have in my system (my Gemfile specifies the `jazz_hands` gem which pulls in pry).  Pry does in fact have a `grep` feature, e.g. `history --grep Nomination` will give me lines 1 and 3-6 above.  It also has a `tail` feature. These are documented here:  https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/History

Comment: Actually, pry's history command is `hist` -- I'm not sure how `history` actually is a legitimate command.

Comment: `history` and `hist` are aliases in pry :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `~/.irb-history` for this purpose. So, the following can be used (you must be knowing how to do this, but this is only for reference):

```
tail -fn0 ~/.irb-history  # for tailing
cat ~/.irb-history | grep something # for searching
```

Note that, you might have both the files: `~/.irb-history` and `~/.irb_history`, and any one of them can be more up to date than the other. I have not been able to resolve this mystery yet. So, use the one you find more suitable for yourself.

---

**UPDATE**: You can access history in a variable using the following logic (it took me a while to read the code Pry uses, try `edit history` inside pry):

```
 def pry_history
   arr = []
   history = Pry::History.new
   history.send(:read_from_file) do |line|
     arr.push line.chomp
   end
   arr
 end
```

Now, you can simply call `pry_history` to get an array of pry's history. You can further save it inside your `.pryrc` configuration file and use it whenever you want in pry.

Comment: Would you know how to do this in a more "Rubyish" way?  E.g., direct manipulation of this `history` command from within the rails console?  I don't see an object getting returned that I can manipulate, seems like that would be nice.

Comment: do you want to manipulate history in a script or within irb console?

Comment: ... within irb console

Comment: I would still like some ways of manipulating whatever it is that pry's history command gives me.

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to rails console
2. press `<ctrl> + r` and type few letters of the command.
3. use `<ctrl> + r` to choose other commands that match the search
4. use `<ctrl> + <shift> + r` to choose the command in the reverse direction

Exactly like the `<ctrl> + r` in bash shell

Answer (score 2):

Probably this is what you are looking for:

```
def search_history(filter)
    puts `cat ~/.irb-history | grep "#{filter}"`
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that if you are using `pry` then the history file will be located at `~/.pry_history`. You may also come across this history file `.byebug_history`.

I've added the following commands to my `~/.pryrc` config file.

```rb
Pry.config.commands.alias_command 'find.history', 'hist -G'

Pry::Commands.command 'search.history', 'filter commands in the history using fzf and output the selected command' do
  puts `cat ~/.pry_history | sort | uniq | fzf --tac --tiebreak=index --height=20`
end

Pry::Commands.command 'search.history.run', 'filter commands in the history using fzf and execute the selected command' do
  _pry_.input = StringIO.new(`cat ~/.pry_history | sort | uniq | fzf --tac --tiebreak=index --height=20 | perl -pe 'chomp if eof'`)
end
```